# ASP.NET WebForms Url 'prn' param error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

There is a strange error happening to me, current web.config for handling errors.

```
   <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <clear />
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/ErrorHandler/404Response.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
     <error statusCode="500" path="/ErrorHandler/ErrorMain.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   </httpErrors>

<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorHandler/ErrorMain.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorHandler/404Response.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorHandler/ErrorMain.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

`IIS 10 Webserver`

This url https://localhost:44327/coins/view/coin/prn (this `prn` or `con` parameter) gives me error, if i put prm or any other parameter it works.

[image: Here it gives me 404 error but no friendly 404 page found, it happens just on this 'prn' parameter]

[image: Here i changed the parameter name from 'prn' to 'prp' it's showing the friendly page]

Why it gives me this error just on 'prn' parameter ?

Comment: This is web forms not mvc?

Comment: Yes, this is Web Forms, i found no explication for this issue, never happend

Comment: Can you elaborate on "if i put prm or any other parameter it works."? Does any other "working" parameter load an actual, non-error page? Or a different kind of error page? I'm trying to understand if you are debugging your error page config or an actual webforms page config.

Comment: "Does any other "working" parameter load an actual, non-error page?" Any other parameter returns the 404 Friendly error page. This "prn" parameter returns the raw error "Server Error / In application"